# tesseract: Recognize plain multi-digit number

Tags: ocr, tesseract

for some strange reason, `tesseract` is not able to recognize the following image. I tried various [config options](https://ai-facets.org/tesseract-ocr-best-practices/) such as:

- `--psm 13`: "Treat the image as a single text line"
- `tessedit_char_whitelist=012345678iI'`: Only allow numbers (and i's that can be replaced later).

This is the image:

[image: plain number]

Maybe it's my preprocessing, but to me the picture looks good (I also tried increasing the borders around the number). Any advice would be highly appreciated! Couldn't find anything helpfull neither Google or SO.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: `pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='digits')`